# Google Cloud - Can connect to a database bound to local IP address using external IP

Tags: networking

Got a weird case at my hands now. It seems that when I set the bind address in my database configuration to the internal IP address (eg. 10.132.0.1) I can still connect to it from the outside world by using external IP. Can someone please explain me how is that even possible? It's not a database config issue, verified it with several different things.

Comment: Is the external address assigned to the VM itself (i.e. can you see it in `ip addr`), or is it handled by GCP NAT?

Comment: Yes it is. In a firewall I had a port 8080 opened with the following specified ports and protocols "tcp; udp: 8080", it seems like it opened entire tcp to the entire world but I am almost sure that in the past you just went like this to open both protocols for 8080. Now I am uncertain  if this should automatically connect you to the database if the bind address is set to a local IP?

Comment: I need to rephrase... Is your (or GCP's) firewall directly sending packets to the external address, or is it rewriting (NAT-ing / "port-forwarding") the external address to the internal one?